# Is there a way to reach parent's sibling in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a button inside a div. When clicked, i will need to grab the length of a list that is a sibling to the parent container. maybe so even a grandparent container.

The gist of the code looks something like this below. (My actual code is actually nested deeper than this example. I would like to know how to target part a sibling of a parent or grandparents or even great great grandparent...)

HTML

```
<div>
  <div class="button-parent">
    <div class="button-containers">
      <button>Click Here!</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-container">
    <ul class="lists">
      <li>bar</li>
      <li>bar</li>
      <li>bar</li>
      <li>bar</li>
      <li>bar</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

jquery

```
$('button').parent('button-parent')
           .closest('list-containers').length
```

Comment: Probably looking for the [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) selector, but you could always do `querySelectorAll`, too

Comment: i will have multiple loops like above. I would only like to target the list0container pertaining to that specific wrapper. Using a querySelectorAll will select all elements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.closest()` finds the closest ancestor (parent), so it won't find your `.list-container`.

You can do this a few ways though...

1. Give your surrounding `div` a class and use `.find()` to locate your list if it is the only list in your parent div:

   ```
    $('button').closest('.parent-div').find('.list-container');
   ```
2. Use `next()` if `.list-container` will always be the next item after `.button-parent`:

   ```
    $('button').closest('.button-parent').next('.list-container');
   ```
3. You can use `.siblings()` if `.list-container` will always be on the same DOM level as `.button-parent`:

   ```
    $('button').closest('.button-parent').siblings('.list-container');
   ```

From there you can fulfil the rest of your requirement to capture the length of the list by selecting all the `li` elements and counting them. If we use number 1 above as an example, it might look something like this:

```js
const list = $('button').closest('.parent-div').find('.lists');
const items = list.children();
const count = items.length;
```

*NOTE: The selection for `list` in this example targets `ul.lists` rather than `.list-container`, as this allows us to count using `children()`, which is much less intensive than `find()`.*

Comment: You can escape the auto numbering list detection in your post by putting a backslash between the number and the decimal. This will allow your code lines to be detected as code.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use **Use parents([selector]) or closest([selector]) with siblings([selector])**

- parents() looks for ancestors, closest() be used as well if you want to select only the first going upward in the ancestry
- siblings() select for siblings
- you can pass them selectors or use eq()
- one more things your jquery snippet doesn't seem to include . for class selector

Three methods that I tried and worked are

```
$('button').parents().eq(1).siblings('.list-container');
$('button').parents('.button-parent').siblings('.list-container');
$('button').closest('.button-parent').siblings('.list-container'));
```

Check out this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ggo9a5vz/1/), i have selected list-container using the three methods